# C# NotFiniteNumberException Doesn't work

Tags: c#, exception, floating-point

I want my program to throw an exception when some floating point variable reaches infinity or is Nan NotFiniteNumberException which looks like a solution but there is a problem. 
This

```
try
{
    Single x = 5;
    x = x / 0;
    x = x + 1;
}
catch (NotFiniteNumberException ex)
{
    //bla bla bla 
}
```

won't throw anything.

I'm aware of `IsNan` and `IsInfinity` methods but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you sure that doesn't throw a DivisionByZeroException?

Comment: @Xcaliburp: Dividing floating-point numbers by zero is legal in C# and results in infinity.

Comment: corect you statement.. it should be 
"won't catch anything" instead of "won't throw anything"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because your division won't throw a `NotFiniteNumberException`. It will simply return infinity for `x`.

From the [documentation of NotFiniteNumberException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notfinitenumberexception.aspx):

> NotFiniteNumberException is available for programming languages that do not support the concepts of infinity and Not-a-Number in floating-point operations.

C# *does* support infinity and Not-a-Number for floating-point operations, so this exception does not apply here. You need to manually check the value of `x` after performing the division.

Comment: Well It isn't what i was hoping for but i answers my question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The NotFiniteNumberException is only there as support for languages which do not natively support infinity.  C# will never throw this exception.  See [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpInfinity.aspx) for one example.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, if you want to get an exception for reaching inf or nan, see my answer with code example here:
[How do I force the C# compiler to throw an exception when any math operation produces 'NaN'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251507/how-do-i-force-the-c-sharp-compiler-to-throw-an-exception-when-any-math-operatio/17859645#17859645)

There, only exceptions for NaN are set, but feel free to look into Visual Studio's version of float.h for other flags, and here: http://www.fortran-2000.com/ArnaudRecipes/CompilerTricks.html#x86_FP for an example on how to set them.

You will not get a NotFiniteNumberException-exception, though, but rather a System.ArithmeticException (tested on VS 2012).

Answer (score -1):

Ehhh,

x = x / 0;

will cause a "DivisionByZeroException", so you're not gonna catch much here.

Comment: Dividing floating-point numbers by zero is legal in C# and results in infinity.