# Visual Studio C# 2010/2013 - break on float NaN

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, floating-point-exceptions

I found this very useful question on how to break on invalid float operations in C++: [Visual Studio C++ 2008 / 2010 - break on float NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454582/visual-studio-c-2008-2010-break-on-float-nan). How can I achieve the same thing in C#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251507/how-do-i-force-the-c-sharp-compiler-to-throw-an-exception-when-any-math-operatio?

Comment: You don't. You need to workaround it, see CodeCasters linked question.